# Updating stacked Bar Chart d3 with multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, slider, multiple-databases

I have created a stacked bar chart in d3, with a slider. I want to use this slider to switch different datasets (.csv). Every csv file is named as follows: "cf_"+ costs +"_ma_1_pi_1_bh_1.csv". The variable 'costs' is the output of the slider with steps of 0.5 in between 0.5 and 3. Switching between the different data set works with the code below, but I want the bar chart to update immediately after switching the slider. I am aware that I need to use d3 fucntions (exit, enter, remove), but I can't get it working. Hope someone could help me out!

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 240, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#2F8FCC", "#FD2925", "#A6DA78", "#9059B7"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("cf_"+ costs +"_ma_1_pi_1_bh_1.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var mystate = d.State; //add to stock code
    var y0 = 0;
    //d.factors = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.factors = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {mystate:mystate, name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.factors[d.factors.length - 1].y1;

  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
     .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9  )
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
    
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");
      //.text("Population");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + "0" + ",0)"; });
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; })

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.factors; 
      })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("x",function(d) { //add to stock code
          return x(d.mystate)
        })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        classLabel = d.name.replace(/\s/g, ''); //remove spaces
        return "class" + classLabel;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  state.selectAll("rect")

       .on("mouseover", function(d){
       
          var delta = d.y1 - d.y0;
          var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
          var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"));
          var height = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("height"))

          d3.select(this).attr("stroke","blue").attr("stroke-width",0.2);

          svg.append("text")
          .attr("x",xPos)
          .attr("y",yPos +height/2)
          .attr("class","tooltip")
          .text(d.name +": "+ delta); 
          
       })
 
       .on("mouseout",function(){
          svg.select(".tooltip").remove();
          d3.select(this).attr("stroke","pink").attr("stroke-width",0.2);
                                
        })


  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  //reverse order to match order in which bars are stacked    

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color)
      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "id" + d.replace(/\s/g, '');
      })
      

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Cost and Financials
<div id="slider" class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min=".5" max="3" value="1" step=".5" id="myRange" name="CostRange">
    <p>Weight Multiplier: <span id="costs"></span></p>
  <script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("costs");
costs = output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
</div>
<div id="barchart">
<script type="text/javascript" src= "stackedclickable5.js" ></script>
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Here are two of my .csv files

cf_1_ma_1_pi_1_bh_1.csv:

`State,Cost and Financials,Multi-actor Complexity,Physical Interdependencies,Behavior
Lighting switch incandescent to LED (residential),1,0,0,1
Cars full hybrid,2,0,0,1
Air Transport,1,1,2,1
Agronomy Practices,1,1,2,1
Cropland nutrient management,0,3,1,2
Clinker substition by fly ash,0,3,2,1
Grassland management,0,3,1,2
PV panels homes,3,1,1,2
Composting new waste,2,3,2,1
Energy efficiency 1 Iron & steel,4,1,2,1
Cars plug-in hybrid,2,3,1,3
Buidling Efficiency New Build,4,2,1,2
Residential appliances,3,2,2,3
Electricity from landfill gas,4,4,1,1
Battery Electric Vehicles,3,3,1,4
Small hydro,5,3,3,2
Nuclear,6,5,2,2
Bioethanol lignocellulosic,4,3,4,3
Geothermal,6,5,3,2
High penetration wind,5,5,4,2
Reduced intensive agriculture conversion,4,5,4,3
Reduced deforestation from timber harvesting,4,5,4,3
Coal CCS new build,6,5,4,3
Coal CCS retrofit,6,5,6,5`

cf_2_ma_1_pi_1_bh_1.csv

`State,Cost and Financials,Multi-actor Complexity,Physical Interdependencies,Behavior
Lighting switch incandescent to LED (residential),2,0,0,1
Cars full hybrid,4,0,0,1
Air Transport,2,1,2,1
Agronomy Practices,2,1,2,1
Cropland nutrient management,0,3,1,2
Clinker substition by fly ash,0,3,2,1
Grassland management,0,3,1,2
PV panels homes,6,1,1,2
Composting new waste,4,3,2,1
Energy efficiency 1 Iron & steel,8,1,2,1
Cars plug-in hybrid,4,3,1,3
Buidling Efficiency New Build,8,2,1,2
Residential appliances,6,2,2,3
Electricity from landfill gas,8,4,1,1
Battery Electric Vehicles,6,3,1,4
Small hydro,10,3,3,2
Nuclear,12,5,2,2
Bioethanol lignocellulosic,8,3,4,3
Geothermal,12,5,3,2
High penetration wind,10,5,4,2
Reduced intensive agriculture conversion,8,5,4,3
Reduced deforestation from timber harvesting,8,5,4,3
Coal CCS new build,12,5,4,3
Coal CCS retrofit,12,5,6,5`